# R relation with 5 equivalence classes and RL

Tags: math, automata

***Question - Prove or dis-prove if R subset of Sigma star x Sigma star inveriant from right with 5 equivalence classes, then exists at least 10 languages that R partitions RL.***

i think i need to dis-prove this but i dont realy know how,
i started to think about number of equivalence classes of R, and because its have - 5
then RL most have at most - 5 equivalence classes.
thats my lead for now, cant think of anything else.

```
assuming exists 10 languages that R partitions RL, let x,y words that xRy
hence R have 5 equivalence classes index(RL) <= index(R)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Because this question is about pure CS theory, it's a better fit at cs.stackexchange.com. You may want to consider asking this question there instead.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what is being asked. I understand R is a binary relation on the set of all strings over some alphabet Sigma. Can you explain what "invariant from right" means? I understand it has five equivalence classes and is therefore an equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetric and transitive). What does "then exists at least 10 languages that R partitions RL" mean? Specifically, "that R partitions RL"? Every equivalence relation on a set partitions that set and all its subsets.